# Android "custom" Spinner

Tags: android, localization, spinner, locale, android-spinner

What I need to achieve is a `Spinner` with these properties:

- The `Spinner` allows the user to select from a fixed set of strings. Those strings are localized, so an English user has different choices than a French user.
- When I try to retrieve the value of the selected item of the `Spinner`, I don't want it to return the localized value of that selected item, but rather the "non-localized" one (in my case, the English value of that string).

How could I achieve this kind of thing? Would a custom `Adapter` suffice? I've been stucking here for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a custom `Adapter` was sufficient to do the trick. I've also defined a layout resource (for elements in the spinner) containing two `TextView`s: one with visibility="Visible" and one with visibility="Gone". The former holds the localized value, while the latter holds the english value.

Answer (score 0):

In your string.xml put

```
 <string-array name="language">
    <item>English</item>
    <item>Franch</item>
    </string-array>
```

In Your XML where you use spinner

```
       <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/language"
         android:layout_width="60dp"
         android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:entries="@array/language"></Spinner>
```

and finally on java file

```
 Spinner  language1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.language);
language.getSelectedView().toString())
```

it work for me..

Comment: Consider this: you have more than one string-array named "languages", one for the english locale and one for the french locale. In this case, an english user would have these entries in the spinner: "English", "French". A french user, instead, would have these entries: "Anglais", "Français". What i want to achieve is this: when a user selects "English" or "Anglais" i want the spinner to return me "English", and when a user selects "French" or "Français" i want it to return me "French"